# Is there alternative/solution for a Bootstrap 5 dropdown select with many options?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, select, dropdown, bootstrap-5

I'm using a Bootstrap 5 dropdown as select to choose a year.

As the list of years is quite big, it doesn't look good, and even worse if "falls off" the bottom of the screen.

```
  <div class="dropdown w-100 mb-sm-0 mb-3" data-bs-toggle="select">
    <button class="btn bbtn-link btn-outline-secondary btn-lg fw-normal dropdown-toggle ps-2 ps-sm-3" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="dropdown-toggle-label">Any year</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="dropdown-item-label">Any year</span></a></li>
        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="dropdown-item-label">2022</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="dropdown-item-label">2021</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="dropdown-item-label">2020</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="dropdown-item-label">2019</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="dropdown-item-label">2018</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="dropdown-item-label">2017</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="dropdown-item-label">2016</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="dropdown-item-label">2015</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="dropdown-item-label">2014</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="dropdown-item-label">2013</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="dropdown-item-label">2012</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="dropdown-item-label">2011</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="dropdown-item-label">2010</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="dropdown-item-label">2009</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="dropdown-item-label">2008</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="dropdown-item-label">2007</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="dropdown-item-label">2006</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="dropdown-item-label">2005</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="dropdown-item-label">2004</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="dropdown-item-label">2003</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="dropdown-item-label">2002</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="dropdown-item-label">2001</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="dropdown-item-label">2000</span></a></li>
        ..
    </ul>
  </div>
```

1. Are there any better patterns for this?
2. Is it possible to have nested dropdown?
3. Would it be possible also vertically display the years in the dropdown, so multiple years per "row".

like:

```
<select>
2021 2022
2016 2017 2018 2019 2020
2011 2012 2013 2014 2015
..
</select>
```